# What's the difference between using ArrayList, or dynamically growing an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a fundamental difference in Java between an `ArrayList`, and a class that uses regular arrays to store items, has an index to keep track of the number of items in the list, and automatically increases the size of the array when it runs out of space?

```java
class myArrayList {
    private int[] array = new int[10];
    private int itemsInArray = 0;

    private void increaseArraySize() {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 10];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
        array = newArray;
    }

    public void put(int i) {
        if (itemsInArray == array.length)
        {
            increaseArraySize();
        }
        array[itemsInArray] = i;
        itemsInArray++;
    }

    public int get(int idx) {
        return array[idx];
    }

    public int size() {
        return itemsInArray;
    }
}
```

An `ArrayList` has some additional methods my class doesn't have (that I could add), and implements the `List` interface, but other than that, is `ArrayList` just for convenience? Do both use the heap to store data?

Comment: The fundamental difference is that particular wheel has already been invented.  Sure it's merely 'convenient', but that's true for practically everything in java.util.*; we *could* do it ourselves, but what'd be the point?

Comment: You can find `lib\src.zip` in the JDK, including `ArrayList.java`. Or just find one [online](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java). One important difference is that `Collection`s (including `List`) store objects, while you can have arrays of primitive types.

Comment: Well, in addition to being convenient, it's also had decades of making sure there aren't any bugs.

Comment: "Do both use the heap to store data?" - Yes.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone assumed I'm trying to reinvent the wheel when all I did was ask how a wheel is made to understand how it works, and its performance implications...

Comment: Johm - unfortunately your question's title implies that you are asking asking about utility rather than performance.  And then you ask about "fundamental differences".  The most fundamental difference between `ArrayList` and your partial class is that the former is complete and tested!  Based on what you actually wrote and asked in your question, it was (IMO) a fair assumption that you were reinventing the wheel.  (If all you wanted to know was *how* `ArrayList` manages storage and / or the performance implications, you should have asked that directly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a fundamental difference in Java between an `ArrayList`, and a class that uses regular arrays to store items, has an index to keep track of the number of items in the list, and automatically increases the size of the array when it runs out of space?

In general no.  Under the hood, `ArrayList` is just an ordinary pure Java class i.e. no native code. It is (roughly speaking!) doing what your code does.

But (as the comments say) it already exists.  You don't need to design it, code it, debug it, tune it ...  You just use it!  Also read [Basil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75191416/139985)!

However, I would note that your version is different from `ArrayList` in some (other) important respects:

- A `myArrayList` holds **only** `int` values.  It is not generic.
- An `ArrayList` holds objects. If you needed a list of integers you would need to use `Integer` as the type parameter rather than `int`.  (Because that's the way that Java generic classes work.)
- In `myArrayList`, a `set` call beyond the end of the list will grow the list.  It is behaving more like a dynamic array than a list.
- In `ArrayList`, a `set` call beyond the end of the list will throw an exception.

If you want a Java "list" type that is specialized for `int` or some other primitive type, there are existing 3rd party libraries; e.g. the GNU Trove library.

> Do both use the heap to store data?

Yes.  In fact, if you look at the source code of `ArrayList` you will see that it does something like what you code is doing.  But it is doing it "smarter" and this will result in better "big O" performance in certain operations.

Consider this:

```
myArrayList list = new myArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    list.put(i, 1);
}
```

The computational complexity of this is O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Each call to `list.put(i, 1)` will cause a resize, creating a new array of size `i` and will then copy `i - 1` values to the new array.  That adds up to 0 + 1 + ... N - 1 or N * (N - 1) / 2 copies.  That is O(N<sup>2</sup>) for the N calls.

By contrast, `ArrayList` uses a resize strategy of growing the list by 50% of its current size.  If you do the analysis, it turns out that the average *amortized* cost for N calls to `ArrayList.append` is O(N) ... not O(N<sup>2</sup>).

---

Lesson #1:  Don't go trying to re-implement standard Java utility classes.  It is usually a waste of time and there is a good chance that your efforts will actually make things *worse*!

There are exceptions to this lesson, but you need a lot of Java programming experience (and / or use of profiling tools) to identify them.  Even then, there is a good chance that there is an existing a 3rd-party alternative that addresses the problem.

Lesson #2:  If your goal is to understand how the standard utility classes work under the hood, the best way is to read the OpenJDK source code.  It is good code and well commented.  In cases where it is complicated there is a good reason for that.  But any experienced Java programmer should be capable of understanding it if they work hard at it.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> What's the difference between using ArrayList, or dynamically growing an array in Java?

Looking at the [*Collections Framework Overview*](https://Collections%20Framework%20Overview), the very first bullet item says:

> The primary advantages of a collections framework are that it:
>
> • Reduces programming effort by providing data structures and algorithms so you don't have to write them yourself.

You asked:

> Is there a fundamental difference in Java between an ArrayList, and a class that uses regular arrays

In terms of behavior, no fundamental difference. As the name implies, the current implementation of `ArrayList` *is* a class that uses regular arrays. So there is no point to you writing your own.

Keep in mind that future versions of `ArrayList` implementations are free to use some other approach besides actual arrays provided the contract promised in the Javadoc is met.

> is ArrayList just for convenience?

Yes, as stated above. Rather than have every individual programmer write their own implementation, why not share one single well-written, well-debugged, and well-documented implementation?

Most implementations of Java are based on the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) open-source codebase. You are free to peruse [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).